# How to override an installed language module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, csv, localisation, language

I installed this language module : https://github.com/Imaginaerum/magento2-language-fr-fr

Now, due to the Magento translation loading order :

1. Loading the module translations
2. Load theme translation file
3. Load translation package info
4. Load db tranlation. (Inline translation)

the `app/design/frontend/COMPANY/PROJECT/i18n/fr_FR.csv` file is not working (not prioritary).

I tried creating a new translation package, but it's not working neither...

Comment: Make sure your current theme is COMPANY/PROJECT and locale is configured by fr_FR.

Comment: locale en_US is working in same theme without another en_US language module installed

Answer (score 2):

Currently, language pack translations have priority over theme translations.

This is going to be fixed in Magento 2.2, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/7142